# Mobile Navigation Bar toggler not coming up in max-width of 500px

Tags: html, css

HTMl SECTION

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Harm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Desktop Nav -->
        <header class="hero">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
                <h1 class="logo">
                    <span class="text-primary"><i class="fas fa-book-open"></i>Edge</span> Ledger 
                </h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#cases">Cases</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- Mobile Navigation-->
            <div class="menu-wrap">
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
                <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
                <div class="menu">
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
            <div class="content">
                <h1>The Sky Is The limit</h1>
                <p>We provide world class financial assistance</p>
                <a href="#abour" class="btn"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Read More</a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>

CSS SECTION

    :root {
        --primary-color: rgba(13, 110, 139, 0.75);
        --secondary-color: rgba(229, 148, 0 , 0.9);
        --overlay-color: rgba(24, 39, 51 , 0.85);
        --menu-speed: 0.75s;
      }
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul{
        list-style: none;
    }
    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.8;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        padding: 0 30px;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .navbar.top {
        background: transparent;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin: 10px 5px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
        border-bottom: #28a745 2px solid;
    }
    
    .navbar ul {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .navbar .logo {
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    /* Header */
    .hero {
        background: url('../images/home/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .hero .content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    
    .hero .content h1 {
        font-size: 55px;
    }
    
    .hero .content p {
        font-size: 23px;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 20px 0 30px;
    }
    
    .hero::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
    .menu-wrap{
        display: none;
    }
    @media (max-width:500px){
        .navbar{
            display: none;
        }
        .menu-wrap {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .toggler {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            opacity: 0;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .hamburger {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            padding: 1rem;
            background: var(--primary-color);
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
          }
          
          /* Hamburger Line */
          .menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
            position: relative;
            flex: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2px;
            background: #fff;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            transition: all 0.4s ease;
          }
          
          /* Hamburger Lines - Top & Bottom */
          .menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before,
          .menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            top: -10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2px;
            background: inherit;
          }
          
          /* Moves Line Down */
          .menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
            top: 10px;
          }
          
          /* Toggler Animation */
          .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
            transform: rotate(135deg);
          }
          
          /* Turns Lines Into X */
          .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
          .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
            top: 0;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
          }
          
          /* Rotate On Hover When Checked */
          .menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
            transform: rotate(225deg);
          }
          
          /* Show Menu */
          .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu {
            visibility: visible;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div {
            transform: scale(1);
            transition-duration: var(--menu-speed);
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
            opacity: 1;
            transition:  opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .menu {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            visibility: hidden;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .menu > div {
            background: var(--overlay-color);
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 200vw;
            height: 200vw;
            display: flex;
            flex: none;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            transform: scale(0);
            transition: all 0.4s ease;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .menu > div > div {
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 90vw;
            max-height: 100vh;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li {
            list-style: none;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            padding: 1rem;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li > a {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: color 0.4s ease;
          }
          
          .menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li > a:hover {
            color: var(--secondary-color);
          }
    }
```

I am trying to remove the navigation bar by replacing it with the hamburger button when the screen width  max is 500, the issue basically is when i am on large screens i want the navigation bar to display the normal way and when my screen width maximum is 500px, the navigation bar should change to a mobile navigation Menu

Answer (score 0):

You should add "display: block" in the media query for .menu-wrap:

```
@media (max-width:500px){        
    .menu-wrap {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out `display:block`

```
@media (max-width:500px){
.menu-wrap {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
      display:block
      }
 }
```